# VBA: Get current month in russian language

Tags: excel, vba

I`m trying to get current month while my system language changed to "Russia",it gives "??????".

Code:

```
Dim presDate as String
presDate = Format(Date,"ddmmmmyyyy")
```

my above code gives output as "??????".I`m using Excel 2010.
Please suggest an answer.

Comment: Could you show the full code that you are using in your function definition? (I was able to get it to work.)

Comment: Do you have a Cyrillic alphabet accessible to Excel?

Comment: @Brad:Yeah russian month "фев", this is readable in cells but not in modules or macro.??? You have any suggestion??

Comment: Do the ????s only appear while debugging in VBA or do they actually flow through to an Excel cell?

Comment: @Brad:In macro only it`ll show like this.Immediate window i dont care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyrillic letters should be displayed properly in VBE Editor, including debug window, if you change *Language for non-Unicode programs* to *Russian* in Control Panel - Regional and Language Options.

Comment: Ian:It works.But I cant ask client to do the same. So i was desperately finding one for my solution.

Comment: Will changing the font used in VBEditor to Courier New Cyr help?

Answer (score 0):

This code works. It would be called as '=mydate(date_value)', where date_value can be a reference to a cell with a date in it, a string value such as '"11/2/96"', an Excel function that returns the system's current date (e.g., '=mydate(TODAY())' or '=mydate(NOW()).

```
  Option Explicit
  Function mydate(cel As Variant) As String
      If (TypeName(cel) = "Range") Then
          mydate = Format(cel.Value, "mmmm dd yyyy")
      ElseIf TypeName(cel) = "String" Then
          mydate = Format(datevalue(cel), "mmmm dd yyyy")
      ElseIf TypeName(cel) = "Double" Then
          mydate = Format(Round(cel, 0), "mmmm dd yyyy")
      Else  
          mydate = CVErr(xlErrValue)
      End If
  End Function
```

Comment: chuff : mydate is just a function right?? Could you please get it worked for the current datetime???

Comment: I've expanded the function to handle more types of input, but as I had said earlier, the basic function I started with works when the argument to the function is a cell containing a date value. I'm not sure what's going on with your system: If the problem were with how the function was working, you would get a #VALUE! error. A #NAME? error usually means that the function name that has been entered has not been defined in VBA.

Comment: Chuff: I dont think so you got my problem here. Only for russian language i have this problem. Macro is not able to handle that.(Immediate Window I dont care). And please use this for current datetime.

Answer (score 0):

When I do this in the immediate window

```
Debug.Print Format(now,"ddmmmmyyyy")
```

in the immediate window I get

```
26???????2013
```

and when I do

```
cells(1,1)=Format(now,"ddmmmmyyyy")
```

in cell `A1` I get

```
26февраля2013
```

I think the VBA IDE just can not do non-latin characters (probably limited to ASCII).

Comment: //Change your system language to russian Code: Sub ss()
Dim aa As Variant
aa = Format(Now(), "ddmmmmyy")
End Sub Please try this.

Comment: Results: `aa = "26???????13"` **in the IDE** but then add the line `Cells(1, 1) = aa` and look in Excel. A1 = `26февраля13`